# Move a view up only when the keyboard covers an button

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am trying to move a button when I tapped in a uitextview. I used a code it worked. After 2tap my button goes up.

```
import UIKit
extension UIView{
    
    func bindKeyboard()  {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillChange(_:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    }
    
    @objc func keyboardWillChange(_ notification: NSNotification) {
        // Allows for keyframe animation, moving the button up with the keyboard.
        // It binds the object with the button
        let duration = notification.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! Double
        let curve = notification.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as! UInt
        
        let startingFrame = (notification.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
        let endingFrame =  (notification.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
        let deltaY = endingFrame.origin.y - startingFrame.origin.y
        print(deltaY)
        
        UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.0, options: UIView.KeyframeAnimationOptions(rawValue: curve), animations: {
            self.frame.origin.y += deltaY
        }, completion: nil)
    }
}
```

I have a button named nextBtn. I am calling nextBtn.bindKeyboard() method. After a tap, I get a perfect button position but when I am tried to tap twice I got the wrong position. Sometimes my button doesn't move up.I am not English native speaker. Please pardon me if I have done any grammatical mistake.
[After the first tap on textview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXeJw.jpg)

[After the second tap on textview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jonFb.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Set frame if it not already set to that position

```
extension UIView{
    
    func bindKeyboard()  {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillChange(_:)), name: UIResponder.keyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil)
    }
    
    @objc func keyboardWillChange(_ notification: NSNotification) {
        // Allows for keyframe animation, moving the button up with the keyboard.
        // It binds the object with the button
        let duration = notification.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as! Double
        let curve = notification.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as! UInt
        
        let startingFrame = (notification.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
        let endingFrame =  (notification.userInfo![UIResponder.keyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as! NSValue).cgRectValue
        let deltaY = endingFrame.origin.y - startingFrame.origin.y
        print(deltaY)
        
        
        if self.frame.origin.y == 0 {
        UIView.animateKeyframes(withDuration: duration, delay: 0.0, options: UIView.KeyframeAnimationOptions(rawValue: curve), animations: {
            self.frame.origin.y += deltaY
        }, completion: nil)
    }
    }
}
```

add binding in didLoad

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
         nextBtn.bindKeyboard()
        goalTextView.delegate=self
        

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
```

remove from `textViewDidBeginEditing`

Comment: can you send demo project to test and debug ?

Comment: How can I send you my demo project?

Comment: Send via Wetransfer.com

Comment: we.tl/t-27gcrpHIuK can you please check? It will be very helpful. I am in basic level ios developer.

Comment: let me know when you are there

Comment: actually extension/UIViewext.swift